# Hide/Reorganize Badges on Profile

Tags: feature-request, badges

As badges are usually for positive behavior (or even consolation - Tumbleweed Badge), it would make sense that we be able to display them on our profile as we like.

There may be a few legitimate reasons for this such as bringing focus to badges we choose (which could be a implemented as a type of custom sort) or "removing" (hiding) badges that we do not want others to view on our profile.

For example, I certainly would consider some tag badges more important to me than others. Or, if someone for any reason does not want a badge visible, say Fanatic, they shouldn't have to avoid earning the badge to shape their profile.

Comment: Why would you not want that badge displayed? Is there a specific badge that *you* don't want displayed?

Comment: I'm not sure about some (tumbleweed, enthusiast, unsung hero, others with no good reasons), but none that I have. However, on top of that, it seems that a large number of badges (esp with specific tag badges) often drowns out some badges that are arguably more important - even with class sort.

Answer (score 1):

It's always been about producing high quality content first; Badges aren't designed to be the focus of the site. All badges encourage good behaviour, badges like **Peer Pressure** and **Disciplined** are there to promote good content.

Comment: Sure, but what bout badges like **homework** and **Java**? Isn't there a quality issue if they have the same weight and we can't do anything about it?

Comment: @CameronS Those aren't badges, they're *tags*.

Comment: @Chris From SO: "Silver Badge: Earned 400 upvotes for at least 80 answers in the eclipse tag." Note these are listed with badges on profiles.

Comment: @CameronS Oh, right, sorry. Disregard my earlier comment. :)